# Javassist: Inserting source code at a line which only has a closing brace‏

Tags: java, javassist

For a project, I use Javassist to instrument some code.  Now I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to solve.

The problem looks like this:

I want to instrument source code at line 122 to test the variable `sr.systemId`, but Javassist calculates with the method `insertAt(int lineNumber)` (from class CtBehavior) the next line where it includes the next statement. That means Javassist inserts my code at line 124 instead of 122 because the line 122 has only a closing brace. But at line 124 the variable `sr.systemId` does not exist anymore, so an exception is thrown. I can't use `insertAfter()` (CtBehavior) because it is not at the end of the methodbody.

```
public static IXMLReader fileReader(String filename)
      throws FileNotFoundException,
             IOException
{
    StdXMLReader r = new StdXMLReader(new FileInputStream(filename));
    r.setSystemID(filename);

    for (int i = 0; i < r.readers.size(); i++) {
        StackedReader sr = (StackedReader) r.readers.elementAt(i);
        sr.systemId = r.currentReader.systemId; // line 121
        -> "code I wish to insert goes here"    // "line 122"
    }                                           // line 122
                                                // line 123
    return r;                                   // line 124
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Instrumenting code by line numbers is generally a bad idea, very prone to breakage (there may not even be any line numbers). Can you identify your injection points any other way?

Comment: I can probably get the injection points with pc. Do you know another way to insert code next to the use of the method insertAt(int lineNumber) ?
In the javassist tutorial and many other examples in the internet I only found this way...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the instrumentation? Are you trying to test that the method behaves as expected? (i.e., unit test?)

Comment: I want to instrument a methodcall after each variable or field assignment to test if they are null or not. I'm working with line numbers because they are used in the "test" method afterwards. So my intention for now is just to add additional bytecode to existing classfiles, not for a unit test.

Comment: In Javassist is there a way to get a list of bytecode opcodes of a method (I'm more familiar with Java-ASM) ? If so this would be as easy as checking for a PUTFIELD for 'systemId ' in 'ClassName' and inserting your instructions after.

Comment: Thank you both !! Now I insert my code at specific pcs and not at specific lines anymore, it works perferctly this way :)